# Unable to Record from Roland TD30K Drum Module

Tags: sound

I want to record straight off my drum module using the USB Audio feature of the Roland TD30K with Audacity.  The drum module is upgraded to the latest firmware version and works fine with Windows.  Roland have stated they do not support Linux O/S.

Running 18.4.04 with all updates in place.
Audacity 2.3.3

I will be running a machine at some point with 20.04 and have tested this in  temp machine and it's the same.

Audacity does not see the Roland USB interface.

Happy to supply any more detail that may be requested.

I don't really want to end up dual booting the new machine I am currently building.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  Re "purchasing equipment from mfr's who don't neglect linux support", somewhat difficult when chosing a product on playability/performance under gig conditions is the primary objective.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  Re "purchasing equipment from mfr's who don't neglect linux support", somewhat difficult where choosing a product is based on playability/performance under gig conditions is the primary objective.  Anyway I've solved it.  It turns out the keyboard I grabbed out of the bin for building the new box was a Dell' Y-UK-DEL 1 Multimedia Keyboard' with onboard volume control rotating knob.  If I used the volume knob on the keyboard it killed all other USB sound sources.  Changed keyboard out, re-installed 20.04 and all is well.  I can now record/playback through my drum kit.